# Backward compatibility for filestream databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019, filestream, compatibility-level

I have a database on a filestream enabled instance and with file system tables on SQL Server 2019. I am able to generate scripts for schema and data permitting restore on earlier SQL Server versions like 2017 but was wondering the control checks to ensure that file system files in 2019 still work in 2017. Is there any backward compatibility for databases using filestream?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'm curious about the process. Are you scripting CREATE and INSERT statements, and for the filestream columns want to carry over the OS files instead of that data at the T-SQL/TDS level? Sounds a bit strange to me. Anyhow, more details of the proposed process increases likelihood for good answers.

Comment: You must take the data out of the filestream files in order to move them down-level. Since the data in the filestream file is the actual data, I'm confused on the question you have of compatibility.

Comment: @SeanGallardy in this case I want to migrate a SQL server database that is filestream enabled to a lower version. Morespecifically, a 2019 version down to 2017.

Comment: Right, I get that from the question, but you can't migrate the physical database downlevel, so you'll have to transfer the data by some means, which means you'll just be reading from filestream in one database and inserting it into the other. This means it is agnostic.